# How to identify from where exactly the transaction got reverted while deploying and running the code in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

After testing a smart contract with several test cases, in some cases it reverts back and says

*errored: Error occured: revert.
revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.*

There is no details of the line of code from where the error came,
is there any way to identify the exact line in code from where the error thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Remix terminal, next to the failed transaction (or a successful one, doesn't matter), just hit Debug and then you can step through the function.

[image]